# FileUpload error in the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi
I have a FileUpload and I save a picture and this is the error

```
Access to the path 'D:\Hosting\0000000\html\images\APgt_logo.jpg' is denied.
```

an my local is working well
whats the problem?

this is the code

```
new_row["Product_imag"] = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/images/"+ FileUpload1.FileName.ToString()));
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the problem.  Can you list the steps that you are taking when you get the error?

Answer (score 3):

The user that is running the Web Service process (ie w3wp.exe) doesn't have sufficient rights on the folder you are trying to write to.

Either you have to set write rights in IIS, or you have to adjust the security in the file system. Or both.

You need to provide more information if you want help with that.

Comment: but when I work  from my computer with remote  database is work good

Comment: The database is not what's causing the problem. This error comes from the file system. Where does this happen? Is it on your hosting company's server?

Comment: i'm trying to insert into the images folder a image this is the code new_row["Product_imag"] = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString(); FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/images/"+ FileUpload1.FileName.ToString()));

Comment: The problem is not in your code, it is in your web server and the security settings. Are you using IIS, what version? Do you have control over it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions problem on your web server.

When you run the project locally, the local web server is executing using your permissions which has write access to the directory in question.

When running on the server, the user the app pool is executing under does not have permission to write to the directory.  This is normal as it usually shouldn't.

You might ask this over at serverfault.com to get some good recommendations on how to do this in a secure manner.